# how to transform panel ubuntu in panel style apple finder (watch the picture)

Tags: apple, macbuntu

[how to add this panel or how to create ?](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KXDQU.png)
i like this panel so much, please guys giude me for how to add or make this panel and how to install this on my ubuntu 15.04
thanks in preview

Answer (score 1):

Use this [link](http://www.noobslab.com/2015/05/mbuntu-y-macbuntu-transformation-pack.html) to make your ubuntu look alike mac. It gives option to change font, icons add docky, Spotlight etc.

It will look something like this [mac desktop](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1b073.jpg) when done.

I have tried this and steps are easy to follow. I hope it helps.